# DataGrid binding programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

is there a way to programmatically create data binding to DataGrid, so that in such a binding method, i receive the item in each row, and access data in the item arbitrarily.

for example,

```
class Addition
{
    public int P1 {get;set;}
    public int P2 {get;set;}
}
```

in my DataGrid, i would like to have an other column, output the sum of them, in this example.

in my real problem, this gets more severe and data comes dynamically, i can't even foresee the numbers and titles of columns(real data represent a row as Dictionary).

data could be considered as readonly.

---

**Update**

maybe a better example about what i want to achieve will help you and me better.

i have an array of dictionary here.

```
Dictionary<string, int>[] data;
```

given two dictionaries in the same array, they must have the same key set.

so let say, in such array, the key set is `{"P1", "P2"}`.

but another array comes,

```
Dictionary<string, int>[] data2;
```

in this array, the key set is `{"P1", "P2", "P3"}`.

so i have to do here, is to have a DataGrid, adapting all key sets, and have another column, the value is sum-them-all.

This problem example shows the same essence as my real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm not sure if a data grid view may fit your situation, but it's much customizable and you can fully control it dynamically.

You can modify the class, and add a data member for the addition of P1 and P2, and then make the data source of you dataGridView is a list of this class

```
class Addition
{
    public int P1 {get;set;}
    public int P2 {get;set;}
    public long varSum {get;set;}

    public void Addition (int P1, int P2)
    {
        this.P1 = P1; 
        this.P2 = P2;
        this.varSum = P1 + P2;
    }
}
```

And then

```
Addition add1 = new Addition (1,2);
List <Addition> addList = new List <Addition> ();
addList.insert(add1);
// you need to define dgv as a DataGridVirw
dgv.dataSource = addList;
```

Then your data grid view will have three columns, P1, P2 and sum of them (varSum).

Comment: this is just my example, a simplified version. my data comes with a dictionary, and every thing is unknown. the key point is i couldn't have a class to represent them, so this brings me trouble.

Comment: See the new answer below

Answer (score -1):

Well, the data grid data view source may be a list of string array, where each single DGV row is a string array (e.g. {"1", "2", "3"}). Then, you can convert your dictionary to a string array for each DGV row and then build a list of these arrays and add each row separately to your DGV.

```
int n = 10;/* retrieve this value from your dictionary as your columns count*/;
string [] xx = new string[n];

dataGridView1.ColumnCount = n; 
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    xx[j]=("0"); // fill from your dictionary
    dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText = "someColHeaderText";                    
}

int m = 10;/* retrieve this value from your dictionary as your rows count*/;
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{        
     dataGridView1.Rows.Add(xx);
     dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = "someRowHeaderText";
}
```